# Synchronize MonthCalendar and Datetimepicker

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datetimepicker, monthcalendar

I have a **MonthCalendar** and a **Datetimepicker** in a form. Is there a way to synchronize them? In other words, when I change MonthCalendar' s date, the date of DateTimePicker will be automatically equal to that date and the opposite. 
I ' ve tried these below, but both don't work.

```
datetimePicker1 = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy  hh :mm");
monthCalendar1 = datetimePicker1.Value.ToOADate();
```

Comment: Does your `monthCalendar1` have some property like `Date` or `Value` with type of `DateTime`? BTW, does it have a `DataBindings`?

Comment: @KingKing It' s the default monthCalendar, that Visual Studio provides and I think that it hasn't these properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the default events of these controls to have one update the other.  Double-click the controls to add the event handlers and make them look like this:

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        monthCalendar1.SetDate(dateTimePicker1.Value);
    }

    private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e) {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;
    }
```

Do note that DateTimePicker already has a MonthCalendar built-in, you get it when you click the dropdown button.  Which is the typical way it is used, they are already in sync.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Yes, I' m informed about that, but in this project I wanted to have both for some reasons. Thank you.